# Relativelayout transparency issue

Tags: android

I am creating relative layout,but I have transparency problem.

Screenshot from simulator:

[image]

Why Button is transparent ? This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why Button is transparent ?

Because the default background drawable for a button is semitransparent. If you want to change that, set another drawable as the `android:background` of the button.

Why the `TextView` and `Button` are laid on top of each other because the `layout_align...` attributes align the corresponding edges of the two views.

Answer (score 0):

set the button backgound `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to make it transparent or

`android:background="@color/myColor" for any other color